# edit excel data in vb6

Tags: excel, vb6

Would appreciate if anyone could give me an idea how to edit MS Excel data through some form (vb6). User should not directly edit into excel.

Any sample code would be much of thanks.

Regards

Comment: Please use correct tags in future. VB.NET is not VB6. Also we don't just provide sample code. You need a specific coding issue (so you need to have done some work yourself).

Comment: Too broad of a question for Stack Overflow. See this to get started: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/174451-using-excel-with-visual-basic-6/ . Similar tutorials can be found if you are interested in using vb.net after all. Google  "Automate Excel from Visual Basic".

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/247412

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard form and controls as interface for user. Then, send content of this controls to excel cells.

```
Dim ExcelObj As Object
Dim ExcelBook As Object
Dim ExcelSheet As Object

Set ExcelObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set ExcelBook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(strPathToExcelFile)
Set ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.Worksheets(1)

ExcelSheet.Cells(1, 1) = MyForm.Text1.Text
ExcelSheet.Cells(1, 2) = MyForm.Text2.Text   

ExcelBook.Close (True)

ExcelObj.Quit   
Set ExcelObj = Nothing
```

This is one of many ways to do it ...